# How can I store <String, List<String>> in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

Let's say I have to implement the menu of a restaurant and I have different dish names with their respective ingredients.

For example:

```
Classic: strawberry, banana, pineapple, mango, peach, honey, ice, yogurt
Forest Berry: strawberry, raspberry, blueberry, honey, ice, yogurt
...
```

In python, I would use a dictionary to implement such things. Later on, with this data structure, I would need to write a method that given a string containing first the name of the dish (the key, if I use a dictionary) and an optional list of ingredients separated by commas, returns the ingredients of the dish minus the ones (if) included in the string.

For example, let's run the method `ingredients` with the following configuration:

```
Smoothie.ingredients("Classic,-strawberry,-banana")
```

The out I would need would be:

```
"honey,ice,mango,peach,pineapple,yogurt"
```

I am looking to the most convenient Java data structure to store this kind of object and perform this kind of operation.

Comment: If you're asking what the Java equivalent of a Python dictionary is, it's `Map`.

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials - Trail: Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question. In this way your question stops showing up as _unanswered_ in the question searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `Map<String,Set<String>>`. As it is a key-value data structure.

As for the ingredients I would suggest `Set<String>`, because we don't care about their order, but all ingredients must be unique.

Below code works for JDK11, but can be refactored to work in older versions also:

```
// we normalize key to upper case, to be case insensitive
private Map<String, Set<String>> menu = new HashMap<>();

@BeforeEach
void setUp() { // initialize your menu
    menu.put("CLASSIC", Set.of("strawberry", "banana", "pineapple", "mango", "peach", "honey", "ice", "yogurt"));
    menu.put("FOREST BERRY", Set.of("strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "honey", "ice", "yogurt"));
}

@Test
void getMissingingredients() {
    String key = "classic";
    Set<String> startIngredients = Set.of("strawberry", "banana");
    // when
    Set<String> ingredients = getMissingIngredients(key, startIngredients);
    // then
    assertEquals(Set.of("pineapple", "mango", "peach", "honey", "ice", "yogurt"), ingredients);
}

private Set<String> getMissingIngredients(String dishName, Set<String> initialIngredients) {
    
    // find dish ingredients by dish name. Copy them to a new HashSet
    Set<String> ingredients = new HashSet<>(menu.getOrDefault(dishName.toUpperCase(), Collections.emptySet()));

    // remove ingredients that you already have
    ingredients.removeAll(initialIngredients);

    return ingredients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***How can I store <String, List> in Java?***

That's a *multimap*, and [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) (3rd-party Java library) offers an implementation of it.

Given your example, you could then use it as in

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Multimap<String, String> multimap = TreeMultimap.create();
    multimap.putAll("Classic", Arrays.asList("strawberry", "banana",
            "pineapple", "mango", "peach", "honey", "ice", "yogurt") );
    multimap.putAll("Forest Berry", Arrays.asList("strawberry", "raspberry",
            "blueberry", "honey", "ice", "yogurt") );

    String result = multimap.get("Classic")
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.equals("strawberry") && !e.equals("banana"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

which then gives you the desired sample output

```
honey, ice, mango, peach, pineapple, yogurt
```

From here, you then can generalize further.

(Note that [`TreeMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) is an implementation which does not store duplicate key-value pairs, and the keys and values are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators.)